# Formatting while using "=" syntax in f-string python

Tags: python, formatting, f-string

If there is a variable `var=0.00012646547`, and it is being printed using the "=" syntax feature provided by f-string as

```
print(f'{var=}')
```

, is there a way to format the output which would provide a similar result as the following code ?

```
print('var\t=\t{0:.3e}'.format(var))
```

Naturally print(f'{var\t=%.3e}') doesnot work as it is messing with the f-string syntax

Comment: You can actually use the formatting syntax, kind of. `print(f'var\t=\t{var:.10f}')` will print a tabulator and your `var` with 10 decimal places.

Comment: `print(f'var\t=\t{var:.10f}')` defeats the purpose of using the '=' syntax, in where we only have to write the variable once.